# Golang Echo e.Pre vs e.Use

Tags: api, go, echo

In [Golang's Echo](https://echo.labstack.com/), what's the difference between `e.Pre` and `e.Use`?

e.g. in this code

```golang
e.Use(middleware.Logger())
e.Use(middleware.Recover())
e.Pre(middleware.RemoveTrailingSlash())
```

why not just do

```golang
e.Use(middleware.Logger())
e.Use(middleware.Recover())
e.Use(middleware.RemoveTrailingSlash())
```

or even

```golang
e.Pre(middleware.Logger())
e.Pre(middleware.Recover())
e.Pre(middleware.RemoveTrailingSlash())
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [Echo's documentation on Middlewares](https://echo.labstack.com/middleware/):

> Middleware registered using `Echo#Use()` is only executed for paths which are registered after `Echo#Use()` has been called.
>
> ...
>
> `Echo#Pre()` can be used to register a middleware which is executed before router processes the request. It is helpful to make any changes to the request properties, for example, adding or removing a trailing slash from the path so it matches the route.